# I want a code that changes the color of a text when an action happens

Tags: c#, winforms

I want a code that changes the color of a text when an action happens.

```cs
if (MainAPI.IsAttached() == true)
{
    *code to change color*
}
else
{
    label2.Text = "Not Attached";
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Is this a WinForms app? WPF? ASP.NET Core? Something else?

Comment: this is WinForms app

Comment: So please put that in the question, along with anything you've tried. For example, have you tried just setting the `ForeColor` property? If so, what happened? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to make it *much* clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the color for the textbox you can use the following code snippet:

```
textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

If you want to change the color for the Label you can use the following snippet:

```
label1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```